# Find child plug-ins of features in eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to find all the child plug-ins of a feature ? I know the name of the feature, but IWorkspaceRoot.getProject(String) does not really help me. I get an IProject that I don't know how to convert to a feature object (IFeature ?). Maybe I am on the wrong track and there is a better / easier way to do this. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>You could check that a selected `IProject` is a feature project by checking for the nature called `org.eclipse.pde.FeatureNature`.</del>

<del>Then you could try to use `IProject.getAdapter(IFeature.class)` call, the cast the result to `IFeature`. I did not try this with feature projects, but works well with Java projects.</del>

The correct answer is the use of PDECore static class. This class provides a FeatureModelManager, that would provide the corresponding information:

```
FeatureModelManager manager = PDECore.getDefault().getFeatureModelManager();
```

How to obtain this information? I looked with the plug-in spy to find which project defines the 'Deployable Features' export wizard (use Alt+Shift+F3 when the wizard is selected), and then looked at the implementation of the wizard class, where the addPages() method contains the previously described code block.

Comment: I know it works for java projects. For Features it does not. already tried :)

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect answer, I looked at the code the research a better answer.